# How to keep opened coconut safely?

Tags: storage-method, coconut

Once the coconut is opened , it is attracting fruit flies and other flies. Also, the white color changes to brownish, rendering it unusable.

Is there any way we can "save" an opened coconut. I do not have a  refrigerator yet, so techniques that don't involve a fridge are appreciated.

Comment: I saw a double pot fridge a couple of days ago. You put a smaller clay pot inside a bigger clay pot. Fill the area between the two clay walls with sand. Fill the sand with water. Cover the pots with a wet towel. Evaporation of water will chill the container.

Comment: Why are you opening a coconut before you're ready to eat it?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest just put some plastic foil around it, so the bugs aren't on it. And don't put it in direct sunlight. Since you have no fridge, maybe search for a 'cooler' place (cellar, cabinet, a place where the sun never comes etc.) to put it.

I myself take out all the meat of the coconut, put plastic foil around it and put it in the fridge. That way, it's good for a couple of days.

Do you have a freezer? You can also put some in there. It will be good for longer than a couple of days (up to a couple of months if you preserved it well). I have no idea how it turns out afterwards. I'm guessing it will be a bit less 'juicy'.

Another way to preserve it, is to dry the coconut. But this will of course damage the flavour.

Answer (score 0):

Whole Foods sometimes sells opened coconut. What they do is they break a hole on the top of the shell but leave the thin layer of meat unbroken. They also wrap the semi-opened coconut with plastic foil completely and place it in shallow ice water. Basically you can break the thin layer of meat with a straw/spoon/you finger and enjoy the water. It says on the package the good-through date is 7 days refrigerated so likely you will only be able to store it for 3-4 days without a fridge.

Sometime I pour the water out of the coconut into a plastic bottle and tighten the cap. It will last for at least a day.

Answer (score -2):

Cutting the coconut pieces and put it in the cup of water and for an hour dispose the water and pour new water into that

Comment: And? What will that accomplish, and how do you know it's safe?

Answer (score -2):

Try this...

Fill the opened coconut with salt ...

Salt should preserve it..You can use it max for a week..

Comment: Interesting. Is this something that you have done?